# Adding CSS to an <iframe>

Tags: jquery, html

I have to apply CSS to an `<iframe>` present in my HTML page using jQuery. The CSS must only be applied to that `<iframe>` and not the other parts of the HTML. Can anyone help me to do it using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it using **just** css is to access the iFrame with an id, like this:

```
$('#iframe-unique-name').children().css('background-color', 'red');
```

This would set the background color of the elements contained within the iframe to red, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If the `iframe`'s URL (`src` attribute) don't violate the same domain policy, you should be able to...

```
$('iframe').contents().find('body').css({ fontSize: '130%' });
```

And if it doesn't, it will be on your domain. Can you just put the CSS there in the `iframe`'s source?